# Word 2010 - How can I prevent Word to update linked images

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

i`m working at a mental illness medical facility.
For our documents we are using Word templates which contains the header and footer as an linked image.
The advantage of this is if we have to change something in the header, we have to change one image and all documents are getting these changes.

Now we have the problem that this image changes even if Word is in read-only mode or has been released.
This also affects documents that are sent to patients or doctors and then a copy is printed for the patient record. If the image changes at this point in time, the documents are different and document authenticity is no longer guaranteed.

Is it somehow possible to prevent Word from updating the image when it is in read-only mode?

**EDIT:**

- Setting "Update links on Open" (File->Options->Advanced->General) is turned off

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You may read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before you ask a question. Have you googled before you asked your question? It seems the second entry after your SO question answers your question: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_windows8/word-2013-how-do-i-prevent-images-from/83ef7a21-fc28-455e-8012-bab8dd1c46e8?auth=1 `File`->`Options`->`Advanced` and scroll down to the `General` section and uncheck the box for `Update automatic links at open.`

Comment: These settings are already turned off.

Answer (score 0):

File>Options>Advanced and scroll down to the General section and uncheck the box for "Update automatic links at open."

Hope this helps...

Or You Can Try The Macro:

```
Sub AutoOpen()
    With Options
        .UpdateFieldsAtPrint = false
        .UpdateLinksAtPrint = false
    End With
    ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ultramax,

thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I Have already turned this option off.

Comment: Try this code: Sub AutoOpen()
    With Options
        .UpdateFieldsAtPrint = false
        .UpdateLinksAtPrint = false
    End With
    ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
End Sub

Comment: I tried the code, but it doesn't work either.

We'll probably solve it like this:

1. the links will be updated automatically
2. If document protection is active when saving, the user will be asked if he wants to remove the links. If the user wants to do so, all links are removed by script. The pictures are still there, but will not be updated.